# How to use time frames for destinations in Here Maps routing FindSequence API

Tags: here-api

I need to calculate the best order to make deliveries for a company. I'm using Here Maps routing FindSequence API (as described at [FindSequence](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/api-reference-findsequence.html)). Some of the points need to be visited during a specific time frame (before 11:00am in this case). Thus, I'm using the constraint **acc** for those destinations. I expect the algorithm to prioritise those locations, but on the contrary, the answer put them very early but next day.

This is my request:

```
https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json?start=Origin;4.668216,-74.0663873&destination1=1;4.65656493,-74.04665622;st:600&destination2=2;4.7462899,-74.0562663;st:600&destination3=3;4.6721945,-74.0496587;st:600&destination4=4;4.6638526,-74.0515201;st:600&destination5=5;4.6802897,-74.0599083;st:600&destination6=6;4.68673,-74.05051;st:600&destination7=7;4.7556504,-74.0788032;st:600&destination8=8;4.6518,-74.05605;st:600;acc:mo07:00:00-05:00|mo11:00:00-05:00&destination9=9;4.69521875,-74.03189087;st:600;acc:mo07:00:00-05:00|mo11:00:00-05:00&destination10=10;4.70111260,-74.04937187;st:600;acc:mo07:00:00-05:00|mo11:00:00-05:00&destination11=11;4.6647333,-74.0623414;st:600&destination12=12;4.67798040,-74.04984117;st:600&destination13=13;4.6958095,-74.0277338;st:600&destination14=14;4.7538976,-74.0471541;st:600&destination15=15;4.72231908,-74.02900595;st:600&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&departure=2020-09-30T07:00:00-05:00&apiKey=XXXXXXXXX
```

And this is the answer:

```
{"results": [
{
"waypoints": [
{
"id": "Origin",
"lat": 4.668216,
"lng": -74.0663873,
"sequence": 0,
"estimatedArrival": null,
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T07:00:00-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": []
},
{
"id": "15",
"lat": 4.72231908,
"lng": -74.02900595,
"sequence": 1,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T07:16:50-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T07:26:50-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "14",
"lat": 4.7538976,
"lng": -74.0471541,
"sequence": 2,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T07:37:55-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T07:47:55-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "13",
"lat": 4.6958095,
"lng": -74.0277338,
"sequence": 3,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T08:06:38-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T08:16:38-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "12",
"lat": 4.6779804,
"lng": -74.04984117,
"sequence": 4,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T08:26:05-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T08:36:05-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "11",
"lat": 4.6647333,
"lng": -74.0623414,
"sequence": 5,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T08:44:23-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T08:54:23-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "7",
"lat": 4.7556504,
"lng": -74.0788032,
"sequence": 6,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T09:23:04-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T09:33:04-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "6",
"lat": 4.68673,
"lng": -74.05051,
"sequence": 7,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T10:01:51-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T10:11:51-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "5",
"lat": 4.6802897,
"lng": -74.0599083,
"sequence": 8,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T10:18:34-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T10:28:34-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "4",
"lat": 4.6638526,
"lng": -74.0515201,
"sequence": 9,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T10:39:38-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T10:49:38-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "3",
"lat": 4.6721945,
"lng": -74.0496587,
"sequence": 10,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T10:55:34-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T11:05:34-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "2",
"lat": 4.7462899,
"lng": -74.0562663,
"sequence": 11,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T11:25:12-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T11:35:12-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "1",
"lat": 4.65656493,
"lng": -74.04665622,
"sequence": 12,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T11:59:45-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-09-30T12:09:45-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "10",
"lat": 4.7011126,
"lng": -74.04937187,
"sequence": 13,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-09-30T12:27:22-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-10-05T07:10:00-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "acc:mo07:00:00-05:00|mo11:00:00-05:00;st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "9",
"lat": 4.69521875,
"lng": -74.03189087,
"sequence": 14,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-10-05T07:16:08-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": "2020-10-05T07:26:08-05:00",
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "acc:mo07:00:00-05:00|mo11:00:00-05:00;st:600"
]
},
{
"id": "8",
"lat": 4.6518,
"lng": -74.05605,
"sequence": 15,
"estimatedArrival": "2020-10-05T07:37:33-05:00",
"estimatedDeparture": null,
"fulfilledConstraints": [
    "acc:mo07:00:00-05:00|mo11:00:00-05:00;st:600"
]
}
],
"distance": "109141",
"time": "434853",
"interconnections": [
{
"fromWaypoint": "Origin",
"toWaypoint": "15",
"distance": 8753.0,
"time": 1010.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "15",
"toWaypoint": "14",
"distance": 5943.0,
"time": 665.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "14",
"toWaypoint": "13",
"distance": 10043.0,
"time": 1123.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "13",
"toWaypoint": "12",
"distance": 4369.0,
"time": 567.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "12",
"toWaypoint": "11",
"distance": 3201.0,
"time": 498.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "11",
"toWaypoint": "7",
"distance": 14941.0,
"time": 1721.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "7",
"toWaypoint": "6",
"distance": 13582.0,
"time": 1727.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "6",
"toWaypoint": "5",
"distance": 2466.0,
"time": 403.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "5",
"toWaypoint": "4",
"distance": 3945.0,
"time": 664.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "4",
"toWaypoint": "3",
"distance": 2131.0,
"time": 356.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "3",
"toWaypoint": "2",
"distance": 10962.0,
"time": 1178.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "2",
"toWaypoint": "1",
"distance": 12803.0,
"time": 1473.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "1",
"toWaypoint": "10",
"distance": 6721.0,
"time": 1057.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 412358.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "10",
"toWaypoint": "9",
"distance": 2564.0,
"time": 368.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
},
{
"fromWaypoint": "9",
"toWaypoint": "8",
"distance": 6717.0,
"time": 685.0,
"rest": 0.0,
"waiting": 0.0
}
],
"description": "Targeted best time; with , improvement for traffic",
"timeBreakdown": {
"driving": 13495,
"service": 9000,
"rest": 0,
"waiting": 412358
}
}
],
"errors": [],
"processingTimeDesc": "1490ms",
"responseCode": "200",
"warnings": null,
"requestId": null
}
```

`

Please notice the **acc:** constraints for points 8, 9 and 10 in the request. They should be visited on 2020-09-30 between 7am and 11am. However, the returned solution establishes they will be visited on 2020-10-05, which is not acceptable. How could I force the system to satisfy the requirement without setting a specific appointment time with **at:** constraint?

Answer (score 0):

After checking some other posts in this forum, I found some information not mentioned by documentation:
The waypoint id can be followed by a semicolon separated list of constraints. Supported constraints: before, acc,at,st

The value consists of two timestamps with day, time and time zone information in the format:

acc:DDhh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]|DDhh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]

For access hours days (DD) are abbreviated with two lowercase characters: mo for Monday, tu for Tuesday, we, th, fr, sa, su. Hours (hh) must integer values in the range 0..23. Minutes and seconds must be from the range 0..59. The first time stamp defines the beginning of the access hours, the second time stamp defines the end of the access hours.

My mistake was to let the two letters fixed as **mo** but the week day of the request is a Wednesday. Thus, the right way to codify the time frame is:
**acc:we07:00:00-05:00**.